# installing matplotlib on MAC OSX 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

I am installing matplotlib on MAC os x 10.6.8. I cloned the matplotlib installation files from: 
 git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git

Then i try to build on it using : python setup.py build. I get the following error.

---

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.dev1]
                python: yes [2.6.1 (r261:67515, Aug  2 2010, 20:10:18)  [GCC
                        4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]]
              platform: yes [darwin]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
Requires numpy 1.6 or later to build.  (Found 1.2.1)

---

The problem is that i already have numpy 1.9 installed. I know this because when i do - brew install numpy, I get the following message 
Warning: numpy-1.9.1 already installed

Comment: Is `numpy` installed for the same version of `python`? Try running `python` from the command line, entering `import numpy` then `numpy.__version__` to get the version that `matplotlib` is seeing.

Comment: I finally got it working by using miniconda. So essentially installed python using miniconda. Then added packages such as matplotlib on top using conda install command